# MySQL in php problems

Tags: php, mysql

What I am trying to do is check if the name already exists in the database but the my code does not work it just adds the existing user again instead of saying "name already exists".
Where am I going wrong?
Thank you

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT FROM arms (name, email, mesurement) WHERE name = $users_name");
 if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>=1)
   {
    echo"name already exists";
   }
 else
    {
$query = "
  INSERT INTO `arms` ( `name` , `email` , `mesurement` )
VALUES (
'$users_name', '$users_email', '$users_mesurement'
);";


  mysql_query($query);
    }
```

Comment: I guess you missed a * in your sql query.

`SELECT * FROM arms (name, email, mesurement) WHERE name = $users_name`

Comment: Sidenote: If username is varchar, do `WHERE name = '$users_name'` aside from what's already been said above. You need to select "something". Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 1):

I see three things wrong right away:

1. You're not selecting anything.  You need to `SELECT something FROM...`, even if it's just `SELECT * FROM...` or `SELECT name FROM...`  Otherwise that's just a syntax error.  (It looks like you put the `SELECT` clause *after* the `FROM` clause for some reason.  Try: `SELECT name, email, measurement FROM arms WHERE...`
2. You don't wrap single-quotes around the string in your `WHERE` clause: `WHERE name = $users_name` should be `WHERE name = '$users_name'`
3. Your code is ***wide open to SQL injection attacks***.  [Please fix that](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: It should also be noted that the mysql_* functions are deprecated.  The OP should be using mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

rewrite your query like that :

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT name, email, mesurement FROM arms WHERE name = '$users_name' ");
```